# kivy gives 'Unable to get a Window'

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I installed kivy on my Window 7, Python 2.7. When I run the following code:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

it gives the following error:

> Unable to get a Window, abort.

I tried on Python 3.4, same error.

Comment: Post the full error log.

Comment: the error log: 
[WARNING           ] Image: Unable to load image <D:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\glsl\default.png>
[CRITICAL          ] Window: Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image

Comment: [CRITICAL          ] App: Unable to get a Window, abort.
[WARNING           ] stderr: Exception SystemExit: 1 in 'kivy.properties.dpi2px' ignored
[CRITICAL          ] App: Unable to get a Window, abort.

Comment: I know this comment is late but as per my experience the only worked solution is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51745051/8440358)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option that sdl2 can't find dlls needed to load *.png

- Try to find `libpng16-16.dll`

on my PC is here: `C:\Python27\share\gstreamer\bin`

- Add it to PATH

  `set PATH=C:\Python27\share\gstreamer\bin;%PATH%`

This is temporary solution but it works for me

Answer (score -1):

If you use Windows 10 then you may have two windows 10 installed on that same laptop which then has made it difficult for Python, Kivy and Kivmd to find the Windows to execute the program with so it gives an error.

That is why this commonly happens to partitioned laptops so check your laptop again to know how many windows are installed and delete one of the windows or you can also format your laptop properly to solve these issues. In my case my laptop was formatted.

Comment: "Unable to get a Window" means kivy's window, not the windows operating system.