# Kivy Unable to get a Window, abort

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Please I have tried all possible solutions, I can find on this forum, regarding to this problem. None of them worked for me so far. Please I will like you to help me out as this error has stopped me from making progress learning. I also tried with Anaconda, I get same Error...

Code:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label

class SimpleApp(App):

  def build(self):

    return Label(text="This is a kivy App")


SimpleApp().run()
```

Error:

> C:\Users\USER\Documents\KIVY\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>
> C:/Users/USER/Documents/KIVY/eve.py
>
> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in
>   C:\Users\USER.kivy\logs\kivy_18-10-25_51.txt
>
> [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
>
> [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default,
>   Dec 19 2016, 13:29:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
>
> [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2,
>   img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
>
> [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
>
> [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
>
> [INFO   ] [Window      ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context
>
> [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
>   sdl2 - RuntimeError: Could not initialize OpenGL / GLES library
>   File
>   "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core__init__.py",
>   line 67, in core_select_lib
>       cls = cls()    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py",
>   line 140, in **init**
>       super(WindowSDL, self).**init**()    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window__init__.py",
>   line 968, in **init**
>       self.create_window()    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py",
>   line 272, in create_window
>       self.fullscreen, resizable, state)    File "kivy\core\window_window_sdl2.pyx", line 209, in
>   kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window    File
>   "kivy\core\window_window_sdl2.pyx", line 66, in
>   kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die
>
> [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Comment: Could you clearly indicate the possible solutions that you have tried not to inidicate them back?

Comment: @eylianesc Just know I've tried every possible solution on this platform... I've been going through it for a week now so I'm pretty sure of it... Including github

Comment: What are they ?, Could you point out the links ?, I'm thinking of closing your question as a duplicate of other similar questions, but before that I'm asking you not to do it.

Comment: If it does not indicate that you have tried everything possible, it is like saying and take all the medicines of the world but nothing heals me, and because we do not know what that is, so we will not know how to heal you. be clear and read [ask], also check the [tour]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845704/pycharm-with-kivy-error-critical-app-unable-to-get-a-window-abort  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487308/python-kivy-unable-to-get-a-window-abort. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697876/unable-to-get-a-window-abort. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640466/kivy-with-error-unable-to-get-a-window. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845704/pycharm-with-kivy-error-critical-app-unable-to-get-a-window-abort. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482753/sdl2-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-and

Comment: This are part of the ones I've tried